# Elasticsearch - Retrieving a list of documents which last status is 51

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in Elasticsearch with this kind of documents:

```
          "transactionId" : 5588,
          "clientId" : "1",
          "transactionType" : 1,
          "transactionStatus" : 51,
          "locationId" : 12,
          "images" : [
            {
              "imageId" : 5773,
              "imagePath" : "http://some/url/path",
              "imageType" : "dummyData",
              "ocrRead" : "XYZ999",
              "imageName" : "SOMENUMBERSANDCHARACTERS.jpg",
              "ocrConfidence" : "94.6",
              "ROITopLeftCoordinate" : "839x251",
              "ROIBottomRightCoordinate" : "999x323"
            }
          ],
          "creationTimestamp" : 1669645709130,
          "current" : true,
          "timestamp" : 1669646359686
```

It's an "add only" type of stack, where a record is never updated. For instance:
.- Adds a new record with "transactionStatus": 10
.- the transactionID changes status, then, adds a new record for the same transactionID with "transactionStatus": 51
and so on.

What I want to achieve, is get a list of 10 records whose last status is 51 but I can't write the correct query.

Here is what I've tried:

```
 { "size": 10, 
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "collapse": {
      "field": "transactionId",
      "inner_hits": {
        "name": "most_recent",
        "size": 1,
        "sort": [{"timestamp": "desc"}]
      }
    },
    "post_filter": {
      "term": {
        "transactionStatus": "51"
      }
    }
  }
```

If I change the "transactionStatus":51 on the post_filter term for, let's say 10, it gives me a transactionID record which last record is not 10.

I don't know if I could explain in a proper way. I apologize for my english, is not my native language.

Comment: Why not filter by "transactionStatus": "51" and sort by timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

```
GET test_status/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "transactionStatus": 51
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This one will filter and then sort by timestamp. Let me know if there is something missing.